# Variables in MS SQL Bulk Insert path string

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I need to import 30 .csv files into an MS SQL SERVER database. I can use BULK INSERT, but because of the number of files I want to do it with loop. Each file is named as DP(1).csv, DP(2).csv, DP(3).csv, ..., DP(30).csv.

I did write a `WHILE` loop and with a counter that can also be used to identify a file name, but I have problems with the syntax when including the counter variable in the path name. Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT

SET @COUNT = 1
USE Db_Pc 

WHILE @COUNT <= 30
    BEGIN
        BULK INSERT acks FROM 'C:\Users\JASON SAMUELS\Documents\M-DD\DP('+@COUNT+').csv' 
      WITH(FIRSTROW = 2, 
           ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',  
           FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')

       SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1
    END
```

The error seems to be at the first + just before the variable @COUNT in the path string. This is the error message i get:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

How should i insert the variable in the string?

Comment: is this is your file path C:\Users\JASON SAMUELS\Documents\M-DD\DP(1).csv or your file path is something like C:\Users\JASON SAMUELS\Documents\M-DD\DP1.csv ??

Comment: The first one, C:\Users\JASON SAMUELS\Documents\M-DD\DP(1).csv

Answer (score 1):

it's because you are concatenating an int to a string.

you need to use `CAST( @COUNT as varchar(X) )` (or is it `CONVERT`?).

try:

```
BULK INSERT acks FROM 'C:\Users\JASON SAMUELS\Documents\M-DD\DP(' + CAST(@COUNT as varchar(5) ) + ').csv' WITH(FIRSTROW = 2, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
```

Sorry I'm not around a place I can test the exact syntax.